# Derivative of $\exp[(aX+Y)t]$ w.r.t $a$ where $X,Y$ are matrices of dimension $n\times n$

Tags: power-series, matrix-calculus

Let $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and define
$$
F(a,t) = \exp[(aX+Y)t].
$$
Then, compute
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = ?
$$

**My attempt**: Let $M_a = aX + Y$, then
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} ( I_n + M_a t + M_a^2 t^2 / 2! + M_a^3 t^3 / 3! + \dots ).
$$
Since $\partial M_a^k /\partial a = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} M_a^j X M_a^{k-1-j}$, we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} M_a^j X M_a^{k-1-j} \frac{t^k}{k!}.
$$
The question, therefore, is that whether it's possible to write this power series as a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}\def\p#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}$Given a scalar function, like $f(x)=\exp(x)$, and the matrices
$$\eqalign{
M = M(a)&= aXt + Yt,\qquad &\dot M = \dot M(a) = \p{M}{a} = Xt \\
F = F(a) &= f(M),
&\dot F = \dot F(a) = \p{F}{a} \\
}$$
Evaluating the function with a block-triangular argument yields
$$\eqalign{
B \;=\; f\left(\m{M&\dot M\\{0}&M}\right) \;=\; \m{F&\dot F\\0&F} \\
}$$
Block-matrix analogs of the standard basis vectors
$$\eqalign{
e_1 &= \m{1\\0} \quad &e_2 = \m{0\\1} \\
E_1 &= e_1\otimes I_n \qquad &E_2 = e_2\otimes I_n \\
}$$
can be used to extract the upper-right block, which one might call a closed-form solution
$$\eqalign{
\dot F = E_1^T B\, E_2 \\
}$$

Comment: Hey greg. Thanks for this approach, it's awesome. However, I have one question. I know that the exponential of a block-triangular matrix is also a block triangular matrix. But how do you equate (1,2)-block of matrix exponential with $\dot{F}$?

Comment: Write the block-triangular matrix using Kronecker products
and $(2\times 2)$ Identity and Nilpotent matrices
$$ T=I\otimes M+N\otimes\dot M $$
Start by calculating $T^2,\,T^3,\,etc$. 
Extend those results to a polynomial. 
Thence to any analytic function.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: At the end I got the answer as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} F = \int_0^1 F[a,t(1-\tau)] Xt F(a,t\tau) d\tau.
$$
By using the formula of the exponential of a block-triangular matrix in http://people.math.gatech.edu/~dieci/preps/DiPa-CondExp.pdf.